# Why does `echo 'hi' | tee > a b c` create multiple files, whereas `echo 'hi' > a b c` doesn't?

Tags: zsh, io-redirection, tee

My env: zsh, macOS

---

#### Command in concern:

1. `echo 'hi' | tee > a b c`
2. `echo 'hi' > a b c`

- Command 1 creates files named `a`, `b` and `c` with content `hi`.
- Command 2 creates a file named `a` with content `hi b c`.

AFAIK, only the usage of Command 1 *without* `>` is documented in the manpage of `tee`:

```bash
echo 'hi' | tee a b c
```

I want some help to understand why adding `>` the above code(i.e., Command 1) still creates multiple files, whereas Command 2 creates only one file.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Redirection (`>` in this case) “consumes” the following argument as the target of the redirection; everything else is left alone. So

```
echo 'hi' | tee > a b c
```

is equivalent to

```
echo 'hi' | tee b c > a
```

`tee` duplicates its input to `b`, `c`, and standard output which goes to `a`.

```
echo 'hi' > a b c
```

is equivalent to

```
echo 'hi' b c > a
```

and outputs `hi b c` to standard output, which goes to `a`.

Comment: See also `echo hi > a > b > c` or `echo hi > {a,b,c}` which does an internal `tee`ing in `zsh`.

Answer (score 17):

This is basic shell syntax.
The redirect operator `>` takes exactly one argument which it uses as a filename to redirect standard output to.
The remaining arguments are passed to the command.

So your first command:

```
echo 'hi' | tee > a b c
```

runs the command `echo 'hi' | tee b c`, redirecting its standard output to file `a`.
As it happens, `tee` copies its standard input to all the files given as arguments, plus its standard output. So the data emitted by `echo 'hi'` is copied by `tee` to files `b` and `c`, and to its standard output which by redirection is file `a`.

Your second command:

```
echo 'hi' > a b c
```

runs the command `echo 'hi' b c`, again redirecting its standard output to file `a`.
If you'd care to look at the resulting file `a`, you'd find it contains the text `hi b c` whereas in the first case the three created files all contain only the text `hi`.

Answer (score 12):

`tee` takes the stdin stream and sends a copy to the nominated file(s) and also to stdout. With the `> a` you are capturing the stdout stream to file `a` while `tee` is writing as normal to files `b` and `c`.

`> filename` can appear at any point on its side of the `|` (as long as it is spaced appropriately and is not escaped).

To illustrate, these are all synonymous:

```
echo hi | > a tee b c 
echo hi | tee > a b c 
echo hi | tee b > a c 
echo hi | tee b c > a
```

Comment: _"> filename" can appear at any point on its side of the | (as long as it is spaced appropriately and is not escaped)._ This line beautifully explains the command execution behavior I didn't understand. Thanks.

Comment: @catwith  to further stress the point, `echo > a b c`  can also be `> a echo b c`